# How can I get more than one digit using parenthesis in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I was trying to extract values from a html code using urllib and regular expressions in python3 and when I tried to run this code, it only gave me one of the digits of the number instead of both values even though I added a "+" sign meaning one or more times. What's wrong here?

```
import re
import urllib.error,urllib.parse,urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
finalnums=[]
sumn=0
urlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html")

html=urlfile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup( html,"html.parser" )
spantags = soup("span")
for span in spantags:
    span=span.decode()  
    numlist=re.findall(".+([0-9].*)<",span)
    print(numlist)
    finalnums.extend(numlist)
for anum in finalnums:
    sumn=sumn+int(anum)
print("Sum = ",sumn)
```

This is an example of the string I'm trying to extract the number from:

```
 <span class="comments">54</span>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The plus sign should go *after* the character or group you want to have multiple of. It's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to select and it's not stated in the question itself what the value of `span` is going to be, so an exact answer to what you should do is hard to give.

Comment: I tried the plus sign but it still returns only one digit of the number I'm trying to extract.
I changed the code to this - 
`numlist=re.findall(".+([0-9]+.*)<",span)`

Comment: And yeah this is an example of the string I'm trying to extract the number from  

`<span class="comments">54</span>`

Comment: Try  `numlist=re.findall("\d+",span)` to search for all contiuguous groups of digit characters.

Comment: Your [mcve] would be better if you didn't rely on an external website. You should hard-code a string that you want to search for so we call all faithfully reproduce your problem. If the problem is strictly with a regular expression, we don't need urllib or BeautifulSoup to help answer the question.

Comment: That works perfectly! I didn't know about "\d" but thanks a lot for helping! @Ruzihm

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry I'm new on StackOverflow but thanks for telling me. I will take care of using a minimal reproducible example from next time.

Comment: having the url was very useful though as with web-scraping questions then can be other reasons why you aren't getting the expected result. A good question tbh +; just adding an example of string would have been useful. You can't guarantee web-scraping questions/answers will work for ever.

Comment: I guess this one would as this website was particularly made for practicing a web scraping question. Thanks for the advice though! I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `numlist=re.findall("\d+",span)` to search for all contiguous groups of digit characters.

`\d` is a character class that's equivalent to `[0-9]`, so it would also work if you did `numlist=re.findall("[0-9]+",span)`

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one number in each `<span>` tag:

```
sumn = 0
for span in spantags:
    sumn += int(re.search(r'\d+', span.decode()).group(0))
```